# How to develop application using facelets in XHTML by the Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, xhtml, ide, facelets

I am using Eclipse ide,
i am creating .xhtml pages using facelets and JSF,
how can i configure my ide to work with facelets and JSF.
i need get command help assistence for tags.
Give me information regardig jars i need to include and how to configure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to install jboss tools.

Comment: It is a plugin for eclipse. It is intended for seam framework which uses facelets and jsf but also you can use it without seam. http://www.jboss.org/tools

Comment: +1 Currently I use JBoss Tools for Eclipse 3.5, it is not perfect, but really helps with Facelets+JSF development. Eclipse Helios 3.6 for Java EE developers (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1) has some nice tooling for JSF 2.0, but I haven't really try it to do some real work.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to install Eclipse plugins.  See [JavaServer Faces(JSF) Tools Project](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsf/main.php) on the Eclipse site.
Make sure you use the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers package, use the updater (Help -> Install New Software, select the Helios site) and search for jsf.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 3.6 has only support for facelets in JSF2.0.

JBoss tools and JSF Incubator plugin (eclispe 3.5 only) has support for facelet in JSF 1.x.

You can download plugin for facelets (eclipse 3.5) from
http://www.icefaces.org/eclipse-updates/ It is simpler and lighter than JBoss Tools.

More info in eclipse bug 192393